# how to add url parameteres in MvcSiteMapProvider nodes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sitemap, url-parameters, mvcsitemapprovider

i want to add MvcSiteMapProvider Node for this url:

.../AdminsArea/Orders?type=20

i add this line to mvc.sitemap , but it doesn't show any breadcrumb.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Orders" area="AdminsArea" controller="Home" action="Index">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="OrderStuff" area="AdminsArea" controller="Orders" action="Index" preservedRouteParameters="type" id="10"  />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="OrderGroup" area="AdminsArea" controller="Orders" action="Index" preservedRouteParameters="type" id="20"/>

  </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

what should i do?
thanks.

Controller:

> public class OrdersController : Controller
>
> ```
> {  public ActionResult Index(short type)
>      {
>        ///some codes... 
>          return View(myOrder);
>     }
>  }
> ```

Comment: share ur controller plz..

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla i have added my controller now.

Comment: type is getting value as null???

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla no, it is getting value. i want to prevent creating two forms for just difference types.

Comment: i m not getting u @mortazavi what do u want to do with type??

Comment: I have created one form for saveing 2 types in Db ,instead of creating one form for type=10 and one form for type"20

Comment: then just check with if else for type =10 or 20 and perform ur whatever u want @mortazavi

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla can i check type in sitemap xml? i want to show different title for type=10 or type=20

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a node configuration that matches the URL `/AdminsArea/Orders?type=20`.

If you are using the default route (which defines "id" as optional), you are not getting a match because you are defining a value for "id" in each node, but your URL doesn't use the "id". With your current configuration, to access the node with title "OrderStuff", you would need to go to the URL `/AdminsArea/Orders/Index/10/?type=20`.

It is difficult to guess what you are trying to achieve, but if you are trying to make 1 node for each "type" parameter and the possible values are 10 and 20, you should use this configuration instead.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Orders" area="AdminsArea" controller="Home" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="OrderStuff" area="AdminsArea" controller="Orders" action="Index" type="10" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="OrderGroup" area="AdminsArea" controller="Orders" action="Index" type="20" />
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Then navigating to the URL `/AdminsArea/Orders?type=20` will match the node with the title "OrderGroup".

Making a node configuration match a URL is a manual process. To understand how the matching behavior works, read [How to Make MvcSiteMapProvider Remember a User's Position](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position) and check out the downloadable demos that accompany the article.

It also wouldn't hurt to review your area registration to ensure it follows the [correct conventions](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/78#issuecomment-20918916).

**Update**

Based on your comments, I would say that this is the configuration you are after:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Orders" area="AdminsArea" controller="Home" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="OrderStuff" area="AdminsArea" controller="Orders" action="Index" preservedRouteParameters="type" />
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

That will make any value for "type" match the same action method (and thus "form"). In other words, all of the following URLs will match the node titled "OrderStuff".

- `/AdminsArea/Orders`
- `/AdminsArea/Orders?type=10`
- `/AdminsArea/Orders?type=20`

However, MvcSiteMapProvider will only generate a URL with a "type" parameter when the incoming URL has a "type" parameter. Generally, these URLs need to be created from a source external to MvcSiteMapProvider (such as an ActionLink in the view content or a link from an external website or email).

The problem is that you are specifying "id" in the node configuration but not in the URL.

Comment: Thanks for helping... but i want to show different title with type=10 or type=20.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all helping. I have solved my problem with changing above sitemap code to below code:

```
> <mvcSiteMapNode title="Orders" area="AdminsArea" controller="Home"
> action="Index">
>       <mvcSiteMapNode title="OrderStuff" url="/AdminsArea/Orders?type=10"  />
>     <mvcSiteMapNode title="OrderGroup" url="/AdminsArea/Orders?type=20"/>
> 
>   </mvcSiteMapNode>
```